# UnitTest a helper class (not controller, not service etc.)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

UnitTest a helper class (not controller, not service,

At the begin I need to say that I read a lot of posts for example:
[When should I mock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181/when-should-i-mock)
or
[Should I mock all the dependencies when unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643643/should-i-mock-all-the-dependencies-when-unit-testing)

I also read an article about "How to test Controller in SPRING" or "How to test service Layer".

But right now I want to test a "Helper class" for my "controller" (I'm not sure if there is a difference).

My entities classes looks like this:

```
topics 1:n posts  1:n comments 1:n time.
```

lets look at the method I want to test:

```
void parseToModel(Map<Integer, TimeForm> mapToTime, Time time) {
    mapToTime.putIfAbsent(time.getComment().getId(), new TimeForm(time.getComment().getPost().getTopic().getName(),
        time.getComment().getPost().getName(),
        time.getComment().getName(),
        new ArrayList<>()));
}
```

Like you notice here method have two parameters one is a map (Integer and TimeForm) and time.

It means that to make this test I need to create testObject of Time where I need to set all fields from the method?
    e.g.

```
Time time = new Time();
time.getComment().setId();
time.getComment().getPost().getTopic().setName();
time.getComment().getPost().setName();
time.getComment().setName();
return time;
```

Like you can notice times need comment, comments need a post, and posts need a topic.
This means I need to create all of them?
Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class helperTest{
    //given
    final TimeController timeController = new TimeController(Mockito.mock(TimeService.class));
    Map<Integer, TimeForm> testMap = new HashMap<>();
    Time testObject = generateSimpleTestObject();

    @Test
    public void parse() {
    //when
    timeController.parseToModel(testMap, testObject);
    //then
    Assert.assertEquals(testMap.size(), 1);
    }

    Time generateTestObj(){
    Time testObj = new Time();
    time.getComment().setId("5");
    time.getComment().getPost().getTopic().setName("TestingJava");
    time.getComment().getPost().setName("Unit test.");
    time.getComment().setName("Is it so hard?");
    return time;
    }   
}
```

When I run my test with example data like upper I have a java.lang.NullPointerException.

This is an error stacktrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.timeproject.time.view.HelperTest.generateSimpleTestObject(HelperTest.java:40)
>     at com.timeproject.time.view.HelperTest.(HelperTest.java:26)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Update:
Test passed after editing my testObject method that way:

```
Time generateSimpleTimeTestObject() {
    Time time = new Time();
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    Project project = new Project();
    Topic topic = new Topic();

    time.setComment(comment);
    time.getComment().setPost(post);
    time.getComment().getPost().setTopic(topic);

    time.getComment().setId(999);
    time.getComment().getPost().getTopic().setName("Topic name");
    time.getComment().getPost().setName("Post name");
    time.getComment().setName("Comment name");
    return time;
}
```

But I'm still not sure if its a right way (if some1 could confirm in a comment it's a 100% right way to do it I would've be grateful.)

Comment: NPE at which line. Where is the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means I need to create all of them?

Yes.

> Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

conceptually? Nothing.

Your Parameter `Time` looks like a *data transfer object*. This is somewhat special so that we usually do not apply the *law of demeter* (Don't talk to strangers!) to them.

On the other hand you might want to aplly *information hiding* (and in consequence *LoD* too so that you  avoid the "chain wracking" by adding *delegation methods* to the `Time` class.

Then `Time` is somewhat of a "hybrit" and you would create a mock of it (which wi not do for "pure" DTOs, and do not need to configure all the dependencies of a `Time`object...

Comment: Ohhh, I think I understand now. I need to mock Time and pass it to the method as parameter of generateSimpleTestObject. Am I right?

Comment: I added the summary. After your confirmation about "it's a proper way" to do it I'll, of course, accept your answer.

Comment: @degath *"I need to mock Time and pass it to the method as parameter of generateSimpleTestObject"* you only mock `Time` parameter if you added the *delecation methods* and removed the *getters* to the (complex) properties of `Time`. You *don't mock pure DTOs*!