# Android - mocking issue

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I have a custom class:

```
class MyClass {
    var name = ""

    fun changeName(newName: String) {
        name = newName
    }
}
```

and my testing class:

```
@Test
fun testVerifyMock() {
    val instance: MyClass = mock()

    instance.changeName("newname")

    Assert.assertEquals("newname", instance.name)
}
```

I'm faily new to Unit Tests and I'm kinda stuck, can someone please point me to why I get this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :newname
Actual   :null
```

Basically the call `instance.changeName("newname")` doesn't seem to be changing the name since it's always `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito mocks just ignore what you pass to their methods unless you explicitly tell them what to do. In the case of `changeName`, the parameter is just ignored and therefore the `name` will remain `null`. I don't see why you would use a mock here anyway, so just change to:

```
val instance = MyClass()
...
```

Here's a post on ["when to use mock"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181/when-should-i-mock).

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually still confused on when to mock! that would be very helpful