# Error testing firebase login with Mockito

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mockito, android-espresso

I have login form which sign in the user using firebase and i'm trying to test the login functionality by writing some code and i used Mockito to mock the firebase class but for someone it keeps failing and i think there is something , if someone could help fix the issue , Thank you

- This is my code

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class LoginActivityTest {

    @get:Rule
    var scenario = ActivityScenarioRule(LoginActivity::class.java)
    private lateinit var emailEditText : TextInputLayout
    private lateinit var passwordEditText : TextInputLayout
    private lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser



 @Test
    fun testCaseRealUserLogin(){

        scenario.scenario.onActivity { it ->
            emailEditText = it.findViewById(R.id.loginEmail)
            passwordEditText = it.findViewById(R.id.loginPassword)
        }

        Looper.prepare()
        emailEditText.editText!!.setText("xxxxxx@gmail.com")
        passwordEditText.editText!!.setText("xxxxxx")

        onView(withId(R.id.loginBtn)).perform(click())

        //Mocking firebase
        val firebaseMock  = mock(FirebaseAuth::class.java)
        `when`(firebaseMock.signInWithEmailAndPassword("xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx"))
            .thenReturn(notNull())

        firebaseUser = firebaseMock.currentUser!!

        assertNotNull(firebaseUser)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer. the activity not using the mocked class!!. it uses the real one `FirebaseAuth`.

So you need to supply the mocked class to the activity.

Simple approach is ServiceLocator pattern

First create a ServiceLocator.kt class

```
object ServiceLocator {

    var auth = Firebase.auth

}
```

And use it in the production code instead of instantiating the `auth` object

```
// in activity to sign in
ServiceLocator.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Second you need to replace the real with the mocked class when testing

```
fun testCaseRealUserLogin(){

    scenario.scenario.onActivity { it ->
        emailEditText = it.findViewById(R.id.loginEmail)
        passwordEditText = it.findViewById(R.id.loginPassword)
    }

    Looper.prepare()
    emailEditText.editText!!.setText("xxxxxx@gmail.com")
    passwordEditText.editText!!.setText("xxxxxx")

    //Mocking firebase
    val firebaseMock  = mock(FirebaseAuth::class.java)
    // make activity using the mocked class here ---------------
    ServiceLocator.auth = firebaseMock

    onView(withId(R.id.loginBtn)).perform(click())

    // this assertion will pass
    `when`(firebaseMock.signInWithEmailAndPassword("xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx"))
        .thenReturn(notNull())

    firebaseUser = firebaseMock.currentUser!!

    // NOTE: this assertion will fail as the mocked class will always return null and not the actual value
    assertNotNull(firebaseUser)

}
```

Comment: Thank you mate , that hepled but one thing regarding the "when"() method , when i put isNull() or either isNotNull() the test passes , i guess in the case of isNull() it should fail ?

Comment: Mocked classes used to check if a certainethod is called with a certain parameters, it's not a real implementation

Comment: So it does not interfact with firebase as in real production code ?

Comment: yes. no implementation, just to check if a certain method called with a certain parameter, Generally to check that a certain action WILL HAPPEN in the future, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38260/15262615

Comment: Your answer is appreciated mate , one last thing please , can you refer me to any link on how to mock the listener for example like database listener ( ValueEventListener()) , since i'm getting data from firebase and i listeners for changes . Thank you  , this is the link to my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624912/mock-a-database-reference-callback-with-mockito