# mock a database reference callback with mockito

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, mockito

I'm trying to test database reference by retrieving simple user info , i tried to mock the database references and apply mockito logic on it but for some reason it is not working , the pass is failing , i'm still new with mockito if someone could help thank you , can you please show me how to mock addValuelistener with mockito

- This is my code

```
ServiceLocator
          .db_reference
          .child("Users")
          .child(ServiceLocator.auth.currentUser!!.uid)
          .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object  : ValueEventListener{
              override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.exists()){
                     /// getting data
                  }
              }

              override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

              }

          })
```

- This is the test code

```
  @Test
   fun h_testCaseGetUserInfoFromDB(){
       val firebaseMock = mock(FirebaseAuth::class.java)
       val databaseMock = mock(DatabaseReference::class.java)

       ServiceLocator.auth = firebaseMock
       ServiceLocator.db_reference = databaseMock


       `when`(databaseMock.child("Users").child(firebaseMock.currentUser!!.uid).get()).thenReturn(
           isNotNull())

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following note about mocks

> Mocks is not a real implementation and doesn't know anything about it.
> It used mainly for checking that a certain action WILL happens i.e.
> asserting that a certain function have received a certain parameters,
> with out any guarantee that this function will perform successfully in
> the real implementation.
> Also Note it doesn't return any value like
> real implementation.

So in your code you are testing that a certain data existing in your real firebase. so you need to test with the real firebase instance, there is no work for Mocks to do here. So don't use it

Comment: Oh alright so the use of mocks is limited , so according to your post , there is no way to verify if data exists in firebase database and therefore i should check with real production code right ?

Comment: Yes, don't set a mocked class of firebase in service locator

Comment: Got it thank you